# What is taking up my memory in my Linux virtual machine

Tags: linux, memory

I'm trying to debug an application (`mongodb`) memory usage on a a virtual machine.

`mongod`, is taking 11% of memory. I know this by using `top`

[image: Top output]

but when I want to see how much of my 7.5GB is free, I see none:

```
jenkins@staging:/$ free -g
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:             7          7          0          0          0          6
-/+ buffers/cache:          0          7
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Linux is borrowing unused memory for disk caching. This makes it looks like you are low on memory, but you are not! Everything is fine!

`-/+ buffers/cache:          0          7`

You need check this line for the free memory without cache and buffer. It is ~ `7Gb`.

Read more about this: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/